# OpenGL: Attempt to allocate a texture too big for the current hardware

Tags: opengl, java, graphics, lwjgl

I'm getting the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Attempt to allocate a texture to big for the current hardware
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:320)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:254)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:200)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:64)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:24)

The image I'm trying to use is 128x128.

```
System.out.println(GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE));
```

I get: 32.

32??!! My graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 7970M with 2048 MB GDDR5 RAM, I can run all the latest games in 1080p and 60fps with no problem, and those textures sure as hell doesn't look like they are 32x32 pixels to me!

How can I fix this?

--

Edit: Here's the chaos code I use to init OpenGL:

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(500,500));
Display.create();
if (!GLContext.getCapabilities().OpenGL11) {
    throw new Exception("OpenGL 1.1 not supported.");
}
Display.setTitle("Game");
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluPerspective(45, 1, 0.1f, 5000);

Mouse.setGrabbed(true);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
```

Display is a LWJGL thing, it makes the OpenGL context and the window.

Anyway, I don't think there's anything in the init code that can help me but you never know...

Comment: Could you paste the code that you use to initialize OpenGL and load the texture? I suspect you forgot to initialize something.

Comment: Rey calling System.out.println(GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)); before you call allocate the memory for any textures and see if the value changes.

Comment: Thing is I was trying to use the slick util library, however it seems like it has a check to make sure that the texture can be loaded. Since I can't change slick's code and OpenGL is returning an incorrect GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE (that I can't change) I can't use slick and have to write my own texture loader. Because there isn't anything setting or something to initialize that changes GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE right? Because it's supposed to be a hardware constant?

Comment: Hardware constant will be read from some place in memory. Maybe that place in memory isn't filled with correct values, because you haven't initialized the OpenGL library that was supposed to put it there ;)

Comment: Good point, to be honest I'm not very good at OpenGL and "just want it to work". I'll update my original post in a min.

Comment: @AnonymousMan Read the formatting help on the right side when you are in edit/create mode. SE has its own formatting rules.

Comment: Can you show us what you get for glGetString (GL_VENDOR) and glGetString (GL_RENDERER)?

Comment: You may need to reinstall your driver.  Sounds vaguely like your GL driver is not installed properly.

Comment: Re: "I can run all the latest games in 1080p and 60fps with no problem" - the majority of games use D3D, not OpenGL, and your D3D drivers most likely *are* good.  OEM drivers tend not to be too great for OpenGL support, and with a 7970M I'm expecting it's a switchable graphics monstrosity, which makes things even worse.